# Model service filtering by date

Tags: channel-entries, add-on-development, query

I have recently started using the model service to query channel entries.

```
$query = ee('Model')->get('ChannelEntry')
                    ->filter(...);
```

I have been using EE's documentation to get by for most queries, but am now stuck.

I need to filter entries where a field matches a specific date. There is no mention of this in the documentation.

Previously, when I was able to query channel entries with a database call, I was using the following in a where clause:

```
 DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(field_id_xx),'%d%m%y')
```

Does anyone know of how this can be achieved using the model service?

Comment: Previously when you were using `field_id_xx` custom query, data was saved in same table (`exp_channel_data`). But in EE4, it saves in it's own table (`exp_channel_data_field_xx`)

Comment: You can still use filter for fields that are presented in channel_titles table.. i.e., entry_date

Comment: @Mufi Thanks for the comment. Are you suggesting I keep using a database call? In my query, I need to return multiple fields (which are now stored as tables, as you say), so isn't it best to use the model service?

Comment: No. Model works fine. Find my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = ee('Model')->get('ChannelEntry')->filter('field_id_103', '>' , '1536677819');
```

This code works for me. Where `field_id_103` is my field ID and 2nd parameter is operator (> , <, >=, <= etc.) and last parameter is db value that needs to check.

Comment: Thanks Mufi, but I need to be able to check that (in your example) 'field_id_103' is a specific day. Unless I am mistaken, your code is checking if the code is after the (day) timestamp.

Comment: So above code, `field_id_103 ` is a date field that will store timestamp. 2nd parameter is on me, weather I want to check timestamp is greater then or less then. so if you have to check a day condition should be with 2 filter queries on same field. 1 will be starting timestamp of the day and 1 will be ending timestamp of the day. So you will get all entries for that day.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure why I didn't think of this!!